# Can I check for FHS compliance to a specific version?

Tags: alpine-linux, fhs

I am using [Alpine](https://www.alpinelinux.org/) 3.6.12 in a container for development. Is there a way to check for compatibility against [FHS 3.0](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/index.html)?

Comment: No Linux distro formally follows FHS. No idea why you want to check compliance.

Comment: That’s even assuming it’s technically possible to check compliance, and I don’t think it is — you could check for the existence of directories, but you can’t easily check that they’re being used properly in all cases.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I've been caught out by just how lightweight Alpine is. A package I've installed failed silently and needed some dependencies resolved that were assumed installed. Looking at the FHS section on /bin, wanted to check my assumptions upfront.

Comment: Not sure I follow you. You've got issues with dependencies and wanna check FHS compliance. As to its lightweightedness - it's down to using MUSL instead of glibc.

Comment: @Artem I’m guessing the issue is that a default Alpine container doesn’t ship all the binaries [specified *e.g.* in `/bin`](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s04.html).

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov musl Vs glibc is about how packages are executed, not whether packages are installed.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov "No Linux distro formally follows FHS." some distros document their compliance with FHS e.g. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html-single/storage_administration_guide/index#s1-filesystem-fhs